# Emergency mode after fail mounting windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

It happened after I formatted (from ubuntu) the windows partition, using file system ntfs. Now only boots in emergency mode.

The log throws two errors:
[drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915] *ERROR* uncleared pcf fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

It also say Timed out waiting for decide dev-disk-by.... .device
I think it fails to mount the windows partition, but I wouldn't know how to do it myself. I found some suggestions around the internet but was unable to follow them.

Comment: First thing to try: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just resolved: first I commented out the windows mounting instruction for the boot /etc/fstab, then I was able to start the system normally.

Answer (score 1):

You found the initial problem that was causing Ubuntu emergency mode. It was trying to mount a dirty Windows partition in fstab.

That happened because the NTFS file system was "dirty". It needs a chkdsk run on it from Windows, or, delete the NTFS partition from Ubuntu using gparted, and recreate the NTFS partition from a running Windows system.

Cheers, Al

Comment: Thank you! In alternative, I found it works also by having changed the wrong (old) uuid of windows in /etc/fstab to the new one given by blkid.